# Исключить дочерний элемент в css

Tags: css

Как применить стиль к элементу, исключив один, содержащийся в нём? например, есть

```css
figure {
text-align: center
}
```

```html
<figure>
<img>
<figcaption>Подпись к картинке</figcaption>
</figure>
```

и нужно, чтобы выравнивание применялось только к figcaption, не затрагивая img.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте селекторы ":not" и "*".
Для вашего примера:

```
figure *:not(img) {
text-align: center
}
```

Селектор "*" выбирает все дочерние элементы. Селектор ":not" убирает из этой выборки img.

Comment: таким образом применяется ко всем figure, у которых нет img.

Comment: Вы правы. Исправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    p {
      color: #000000;
    }
    :not(p) {
      color: #ff0000;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]